# Proving that deterministic approximate counting uses log(n) space

Tags: algorithms, counting

We just saw the Morris algorithm in class and we were asked the following:

> In class, we saw a constant factor approximate randomized counting
> algorithm with space complexity $O(\log \log n)$, where $n$ is the maximum
> value of the counter. Prove that any deterministic algorithm that
> provides a factor $1\pm\frac{1}{10}$ approximation to the count must use $\Omega(\log n)$
> space.

I have no idea on how to solve this problem and I would love to get a hint please, just to get me started.

Note that I am not asking for a full solution, just an intuition.

Comment: Just interested to know, using Morris algorithm can't you get 11/10 approximation in $O(\log \log n)$ space?

Comment: Morris' algorithm is *randomized*.

Comment: @Yuval Right. It means a randomized algorithm is performing better than any deterministic algorithm for this problem. So randomization is truly powerful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that such a counter exists, using $f(n) < \log_2 (n+1)$ space for some $n$. When running the counter for $n$ steps, it reaches at most $2^{f(n)}$ different states. The state diagram has exactly one outgoing edge out of each state (since the number of states is at most $n$), and so it must be a path that closes onto itself (together, possibly, with some unreachable states). In particular, there are $a,b \leq 2^{f(n)}$ such that the algorithm is in the same state after $a+kb$ steps, for any $k \geq 0$. Taking $k$ large enough, we see that the algorithm fails to estimate the count up to any bounded factor.

If $f(n) = \log_2 (n+1)$ then the argument fails. Indeed, the state diagram could look as follows: the origin is state $0$, and state $i$ leads to state $i+1$. State $n$ then has no outgoing edge, and this corresponds to the fact that we are not guaranteed that the algorithm uses only $f(n)$ space after $n+1$ steps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I am not sure to understand why, in the state diagram, there would a be a cycle (or a loop).

To be more precise, I don't understand this sentence: "The state diagram has exactly one outgoing edge out of each state (since the number of states is at most $n$), and so it must be a path that closes onto itself (together, possibly, with some unreachable states)."

Comment: Take some small $n$ and try drawing such a graph without a cycle.